# Vb.Net LINQ query nested list

Tags: vb.net, linq

I have  list of cPoint objects. Every cPoint has list of cPosition objects.  I have to make query that returns only cPoints whose  cPositions meet the criteria and and every single cPoint must contain only those cPositions that meet the criteria.  Is it possible with LINQ?

```
'classes
Public Class cPoint
    Private _PointName As String
    Public Positions As colPositions
    '...
End Class

Public Class cPosition
    Private _X As Double
    Private _Y As Double
    Private _Z As Double
    Private _IntervalStart As Long
    '...
End Class

Public Class cPoints
    Inherits System.ComponentModel.BindingList(Of cPoint)
End Class

Public Class cPositions
    Inherits System.ComponentModel.BindingList(Of cPosition)
End Class
```

The closest thing I did is this query  but it does not return filtered cPoints. Every item in query has two objects: 1. filtered Point (with unfiltered child Positions) and 2. filtered Positions that belong to that Point.

```
Dim PtList As cPoints
'...
'my query 
Dim query = (From pt In PtList
             From pos In pt.Positions
             Where (pos.IntervalStart < 222)
             Select New With {Key .PT = pt,
             Key .PTPOS = (From position In pt.Positions Where (position.IntervalStart < 222)).ToList}).Distinct
```

Comment: This is very simple in Linq, see my answer.

Comment: See my update. Advice: C# isn't so bad :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you want the points whose positions ALL have interval more than 222? Just use the All Linq method as the follow example:

```
Module Module1
'classes
Public Class cPoint
    Private _PointName As String
    Public Positions As cPositions

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Needed because we want to construct cPoints object using cPosition list within Linq
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <param name="posList"></param>
    ''' <remarks></remarks>
    Public Sub New(posList As IEnumerable(Of cPosition))
        Positions = New cPositions
        For Each cp As cPosition In posList
            Me.Positions.Add(cp)
        Next
    End Sub

    'default
    Public Sub New()

    End Sub
End Class

Public Class cPosition
    Private _X As Double
    Private _Y As Double
    Private _Z As Double
    Private _IntervalStart As Long

    Public Sub New(x As Double, y As Double, z As Double, iss As long)
        _X = x
        _Y = y
        _Z = z
        _IntervalStart = iss
    End Sub


    ''' <summary>
    ''' Added a property to access from outside class
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <value></value>
    ''' <returns></returns>
    ''' <remarks></remarks>
    Public Property IntervalStart As Long
        Get
            Return _IntervalStart
        End Get
        Set(value As Long)
            _IntervalStart = value
        End Set
    End Property
End Class

Public Class cPoints
    Inherits System.ComponentModel.BindingList(Of cPoint)
End Class

Public Class cPositions
    Inherits System.ComponentModel.BindingList(Of cPosition)
End Class

Sub Main()

    Dim ptlist As cPoints = New cPoints
    Dim point1 = New cPoint
    point1.Positions = New cPositions
    point1.Positions.Add(New cPosition(1, 2, 3, 4))
    point1.Positions.Add(New cPosition(1, 2, 3, 1000))
    point1.Positions.Add(New cPosition(1, 2, 3, 2000))
    point1.Positions.Add(New cPosition(1, 2, 3, 1))

    Dim point2 = New cPoint
    point2.Positions = New cPositions
    point2.Positions.Add(New cPosition(1, 2, 3, 1))
    point2.Positions.Add(New cPosition(1, 2, 3, 2))
    point2.Positions.Add(New cPosition(1, 2, 3, 444))
    point2.Positions.Add(New cPosition(1, 2, 3, 555))

    ptlist.Add(point1)
    ptlist.Add(point2)

    'selects all the points in ptlist that have all their positions with interval start more than 222.
    Dim result = From pt In ptlist
                 Where pt.Positions.All(Function(l As cPosition)
                                            'put whatever condition here.
                                            Return l.IntervalStart > 222
                                        End Function)
                Select pt

    'select all the points. each point, will have all the positions that are less than 222.
    Dim result2 = From pt In ptlist
                  Select New cPoint(pt.Positions.Where(Function(l As cPosition)
                                                           Return l.IntervalStart < 222
                                                       End Function))

    For Each a In result2
        Console.WriteLine(a.Positions.Count)
    Next


End Sub

End Module
```

Comment: No, It seems that I wasn't clear enough.
(Where pt.Positions.Any)
Would return all points that I want. Problem is that I want that that those returned points have only part of cPositions list that meet criteria.
For Example, I have list of points:
Point1, Name=1(Position1 x=0,y=0,z=0,IntervalStart=15) (Position2 x=100,y=200,z=15,IntervalStart=250)
Point2 Name=2(Position1 x=0,y=0,z=0,IntervalStart=352) (Position2 x=100,y=200,z=15,IntervalStart=20)
Final result should be:
Point1, Name=1(Position1 x=0,y=0,z=0,IntervalStart=15)
Point2 Name=2 (Position2 x=100,y=200,z=15,IntervalStart=20)

Comment: This is still simple to do with Linq, but you'll need to create new Point objects: I created constructors to help with that. See my updated answer

Comment: Thanks but creating new points is a problem because I want to retain references to original points. Every change in filtered point/position should reflect original and vice versa.

Comment: Your question was to use Linq. I answered. If you want sophisticated objects that maintain data in lists and views in other lists, just create two List<Whatever> properties {get;set;} do you need help with that? Please accept my answer and ask another question for the other thing you need.

Comment: Thank you for answering. I know how to solve the problem in a different way, I was just wandering if it would be possible with LINQ. My mistake was that I didn't explain clearly enough what I wanted in the first question. Thanks again!